# Why is the startup time of my Electron app so slow?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, native

After building my electron application, and running it, I have noticed the startup time of the app is extremely slow: from the moment I double-click the icon, it takes about six (!) seconds until the splash screen is displayed.

I am aware that Electron is not the most efficient GUI framework, considering that it is basically a Chrome window, but still I think the app should normally load much faster. I have tried to follow the best practices while developing the app, including loading the dependencies only when they're really necessary, but to no avail.

I am working on a Windows PC (x64 processor), and am using [`electron-packager`](https://github.com/electron/electron-packager) to build the executable, like this:

```
electron-packager . "My App" --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --overwrite=true --prune=true
```

I wonder if the antivirus is to be blamed for the slow startup time, but I am not sure. I don't think `electron-packager` is contributing to the issue, given that I used [`electron-builder`](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder), as well, and the app still needed plenty of time to start (my antivirus considered the `.exe` file packaged by `electron-builder` as a threat, and later removed it, even).

What do you think can be the cause for the slow startup time? What else can I try to make my app start faster? For those who are experienced in building Electron applications, how have you countered this issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67982430

Comment: https://blog.inkdrop.app/how-to-make-your-electron-app-launch-1000ms-faster-32ce1e0bb52c

Comment: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/performance